# In CarrierWave, what does retrieve_from_store! do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

The [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/Store#retrieve_from_store%21-instance_method) says about `retrieve_from_store!`:

> Retrieves the file from the storage.

But when I call the method, rather than getting something like a file, I just get an array returned:

```
irb(main):008:0> uploader.retrieve_from_store!('my_file.png')
=> [:retrieve_versions_from_store!]
```

What exactly does the method do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing today. Found something from Jonas Nicklas in the CarrierWave forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/15ALbubO5Uk)...

> `retrieve_from_store!` changes the state of the uploader, it
>   doesn't return anything sensible. You want to do this:

```
uploader.retrieve_from_store!('test.jpg')
uploader.do_whatever
```

> The return value from `retrieve_from_store!` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to use `model.uploader.read` to get to the bytes. It seems, uploader delegates to the file via `Proxy`: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/proxy.rb#L43

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave is not designed to work without model.

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store!(*args)
    super
    @file
  end

  def filename
    SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end

file = uploader.store! file
puts file.path # ok
```

You can patch `retrieve_from_store` in the same way.

It will be tricky to retrieve important info for other methods, so please use another uploader if you can.